# how to rearrange for y for: $\ln{|y|}= \frac{x^3}{3}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Is it $y= \pm e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}$?

I am not sure about whether the plus minus sign is correct.

Just here to look for confirmation or correction! Thanks!

Comment: Please use $\text{LATEX}$

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472999/incorrect-general-statement-for-modulus-inequalities) will help you better understand how to work with equations of this type.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\log|y|=\log \sqrt{y^2}=\frac{1}{2}\log y^2$$
so the equation becomes 
$$\frac{1}{2}\log y^2=\frac{x^3}{3}$$
$$ y^2=e^{\frac{2}{3}x^3}$$
now we see the plus minus sign is necessary
$$ y=\pm e^{\frac{1}{3}x^3}$$